# Get digested asset_path in model or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, fabricjs

I have an `Article` model, which has a field `svg_path`.

I use `fabricjs` to draw a canvas that can contain multiple articles and is modifiable.

What I do currently is generating a `json` that contains all needed fields of the articles, including the `svg_path`.

When I try to use the `asset_path` helper (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) in either my `Article` model or controller it will always just return the path without the digest, which works in development environment but not in production. There I include the helper like this:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper

asset_path(svg_path)
```

If I call this helper in the view it will generate the correct path including the digest hash.

How can I get the correct path in my `json` objects?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution was to call the helper like this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(svg_path)
```

Before that I had included the helper as in my question, which didn't result in the expected result.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this and saving my sanity!

Comment: Thank you for this question and answer. I googled a while with terms like 'Rails.application.config.assets.digests nil', 'use stylesheet_path in controller', and 'rails helpers in a model'.